# Jquery set timeout to selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to use `setTimeout()` for a selector? For example in:

```
$('.some-class').someFunction({
     option1: 500,
     option2: 'blue'
});
```

The function is triggered by the jquery plugin on click of `.some-class`. I want there to be a 1 second delay.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: $( '.some-class' ).click(function() {
  //logic comes here
}); Something like that?

Comment: If `someFunction` is a plugin that binds a click handler behind the scenes, then you should modify the plugin itself.

Comment: Of course it's possible. but... first you'll have to explain what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're after is something like this: [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/tr_santi/2rp7zb8m/1/)

**Creating the new function:**

```
//Create new jQuery function "someFunction"
$.fn.someFunction = function(options) {

    //Set defaults
    var settings = $.extend({
        color: "red",
        time: 1000
    }, options); //Use options when supplied

    return this.each(function() {
        $(this).delay(settings.time).queue(function (next) {
            $(this).css("color", settings.color);
            next();
        });
    });
};
```

**Calling our new function:**

```
//Change some-class to blue after 1500 milliseconds
$('.some-class').someFunction({
    time: 1500,
    color: 'blue'
});
```

Comment: If you're going to downvote my answer, please feel free to give any sort of reason...

Comment: looks like someone is downvoting all of them.. it wasn't me

Comment: Happened at the same time the last comment was made on the question (hint).

Comment: Interesting to say the least, seems to have been reversed though. @CyberJunkie did this solution work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You could modify the plugin `.somefunction` to support that:

```
// store the original plugin:
var orig_f = $.fn.somefunction;
// redefine it to accept a delay property
$.fn.somefunction = function (obj) {
     if (obj.delay === undefined) {
         // standard behaviour
         return orig_f.apply(this, arguments);
     }
     // delay the call
     setTimeout(orig_f.bind(this, ...arguments), obj.delay);
     // or if the ES6 spread operator cannot be used:
     // setTimeout(Function.apply.bind(orig_f, this, arguments), obj.delay);
     return this;
}
```

Example call:

```
$('.some-class').someFunction({
    option1: 500,
    option2: 'blue',
    delay: 1000
});
```